# Compiling CUDA SDK V4.1.28 For Linux?

Tags: compilation, cuda, nvidia

When trying to compile the most recent CUDA SDK from Nvidia (version 4.1.28) for linux, I get the following error:

> error: identifier "CURAND_STATUS_DOUBLE_PRECISION_REQUIRED" is undefined

My google-fu yields only similar problems, and not solutions. 
I have an older version of the SDK (version 4.0.17) which compiles fine. So this might be a bug in the SDK, or there is/are environment variable(s) I didn't set.

Comment: Which example in the SDK exhibits this behavior? What is the name of the source file, and the line number for which the above error is reported? Did you install the CUDA 4.1 toolkit ahead of he CUDA 4.1 SDK?

Comment: @max, if you answer the questions in the comments we can better help resolve the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem when compiling the scan example.The following is the complete message I got:  ../../common/inc/cutil_inline_runtime.h: In function ‘void __curandSafeCall(curandStatus_t, const char*, int)’:
../../common/inc/cutil_inline_runtime.h:328: error: ‘CURAND_STATUS_DOUBLE_PRECISION_REQUIRED’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [obj/x86_64/release/main.cpp.o] Error 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an "answer", but an ugly quick fix is to comment out the line 328. It doesent impact my program, but there is no guarantee that it does not affect yours.

Comment: This is what fixed it for me.